# How to make a set of views in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea, android-view

I am a beginner android programmer.
I am creating a shop dialog for a game 
and each item has a set of views, ImageView (picture), TextView (Description), TextView (Price) and Button (buy/equip/unequipped button), just different attribute values. I don't want to make a custom view because that is a difficult task and not my level.

Is there a way to make a set of views in android?
and how would I use the set in xml layout file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can work around creating a custom view. Just create your layout with all the views you need, and then get the reference to each view by inflating from layout first.

```
View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.your_view_layout, null);
ImageView iv = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
... get button and set click listeners, etc ...
```

If you want to create a dialog you can also set the dialog content view to this "view" object.

Hope it helps.